# Way to log API response time in Cypress

Tags: time, cypress, response, cypress-intercept

I was trying to log the API response time in Cypress, but could not find any solution. What to use, `cy.intercept()` or `cy.request()`?

I was trying to use the advice like this:

```
cy.intercept('POST', '**/create-insurance-view-model', (req) => {
                    const start = Date.now()
                    req.continue(res => {
                      res.responseTime = Date.now() - start;
                    })
                  }).as('apiViewModel')

cy.wait('@apiViewModel').then(intercept => {
                    cy.log(`Time to get the license plate data was: ${intercept.response.responseTime} seconds`)
                })
```

And I am getting undefined in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I solved it like this, thanks to the help from Paolo. Addes custom commands.

```js
let responseTime

Cypress.Commands.add('inteceptasd', (method, request, apiVariable) => {
    cy.intercept(method, request, (req) => {
        const start = Date.now()
        req.reply(() => {
            responseTime = (Date.now() - start) / 1000
        })
    }).as(apiVariable)
})

Cypress.Commands.add('waitasd', (apiVariable, timeVariable, describe) => {
    cy.wait(apiVariable).then(() => {
        timeVariable = responseTime
        cy.log(timeVariable)
        cy.on('test:after:run', (test) => addContext({ test }, `Time to get the endpoint data ${apiVariable} was: ${timeVariable}s - ${describe}`))
    })
})
```

Then I used it in test like this

```js
cy.interceptForResponseTime('GET', '**/get-vehicle-identification*', 'apiVehicleByVin')
cy.get('cebia-price-loader > div > .btn').contains(domData.btnLoadPrice).should('exist').click()
cy.waitWithResponseTime('@apiVehicleByVin', 'timeVehicleByVin', 'description for this api time check')
```

Comment: Also i have this in my commands.js file 

require('cypress-delete-downloads-folder').addCustomCommand();

Cypress.Commands.add('addContext', (context) => {
    cy.once('test:after:run', (test) => addContext({ test }, context));
})

Answer (score 5):

There's two scenarios

- there's a web page that calls an API and you want to test the response time. This scenario uses `cy.intercept()`
- you have an API that you want to test directly (not called from a web page). This scenario uses `cy.request()` to start each API call.

Examples:

```js
it('tests API response via web page', () => {

  cy.intercept('api/resource/3', (req) => {
    const start = Date.now()
    req.continue(res => {
      res.headers.responseTime = Date.now() - start;
    })
  }).as('apiCall')

  cy.visit('/')

  cy.wait('@apiCall').then(intercept => {
    cy.log(intercept.response.headers.responseTime)
  })
```

```js
it('tests API response by direct call', () => {

  const start = Date.now()

  cy.request('api/resource/3')
    .then(response) => {
      const responseTime = Date.now() - start;
      cy.log(responseTime)
    })
```

Comment: I used it like this: 

cy.intercept('POST', '**/create-insurance-view-model', (req) => {
                        const start = Date.now()
                        req.continue(res => {
                          res.responseTime = Date.now() - start;
                        })
                      }).as('apiViewModel')

cy.wait('@apiViewModel').then(intercept => {
                        cy.log(`Time to get the license plate data was: ${intercept.response.responseTime} seconds`)
                    })

And I am getting undefined in the log.

Comment: My bad, it seems that you cannot add arbitrary properties to the response! But you can add it to the `headers`, see my change above.

Comment: see my answer below, I figured out. Your answer was big help with it.